# Ordering django field values in a list

Tags: django, django-templates

I've the following model:

```
class Blog():
     year = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
     title = models.Charfield(max_length=40)
```

Now in my template I currently display this field values like so:

```
{% for blog in blogs %}

    {% ifchanged %}
        <li>{{blog.year}}</li>
    {% endifchanged %}

    <li><a href="#">{{ blog.title }}</a></li>

{% endfor %}
```

Which gives me the following html output:

```
<ul>
    <li>2016</li>
    <li><a href="#">title 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">title 2</a></li>
    <li>2012</li>
    <li><a href="#">title 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

But what I'd like to get would be the following:

```
<ul>

    <li>2016
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">title 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">title 2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>

    <li>2012
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">title 3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>

</ul>
```

Is there a way to do this in django templates?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`regroup`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/ref/templates/builtins/#regroup)

```
{% regroup blogs by year as blog_list %}

<ul>
{% for blog in blog_list %}
    <li>{{ blog.grouper }}
    <ul>
        {% for item in blog.list %}
          <li><a href="#">{{ item.title }}</a></li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
    </li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Comment: perfect thats what i was looking for thanks a lot! Will accept in 7 mins ^^